# Subtitle of a MP4 video is not showing in Safari browser

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, safari

i have created a video(mp4) with subtitle to play in all the browser.

**Issue:**
subtitle is not showing in safari browser alone but working fine in all other browser(chrome,firefox,ie)

**Code:**`<video id="ScreenMediaPlayer" controls autoplay src="" type="video/mp4" runat="server">`Your browser does not support the video tag.
`</video>`

```
<div id="divSubtitleholder" class="ShowScroll">
        <div id="divSubtitle">
        </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.ShowScroll
    {
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
        height: 75px; 
        top: 80%;  
        position: absolute;  
        font-size: 20px; 
        color: White; 
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all test this on all your relevant browsers

http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/

You should see texts after clicking on the **CC** button and choosing a language
[image: You should see texts after clicking on the CC button and choosing a language]

If that works check the sourcecode in this github repository

https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-with-captions

And here are some HTML5 video players

http://praegnanz.de/html5video/

**All of the above was taken from this great article that you should read and try to apply to your case**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video

Comment: thanks.i will try the above link and update you in shortly

Comment: I have already tried all the above link but it is not affected..do i need to enable some setting to show subtitle in safari browser?

Comment: i played this link "http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/"in safari browser but that cc control itself is not working

Comment: how about the HTML5 video players that are mentioned in the answer ? also have you checked if you can use webvtt - http://caniuse.com/webvtt